How to properly put a "safety trade" into a trade strategy? (How to add a long positon to an already existing open one?)
I'm struggling to add a safe trade to the following strategy.
When I run the code, the safety trades are not put, even if the conditions are met.
In the example below, it should buy 2* the initial size if the price gets to -5%.
//@version=5
strategy("NEW", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=2)

// Input parameters
rsiLength = input.int(14, title="RSI Length")
rsiOversold = input.int(30, title="RSI Oversold Level", minval=1, maxval=50)
safetyTrade = input.float(5, title="Safety Trade Drop (%)", minval=0.1) / 100
takeProfit = input.float(5, title="Take Profit (%)", minval=0.1) / 100

// VARIABLES
var float avgBuyPrice = na
var float takeProfitPrice = na
var bool safetyTradeExecuted = false
var float safetyTradeSize = na
var float safetyTradePrice = na

// TA
rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsiLength)

// BASE ORDER
if (strategy.opentrades == 0 and rsi <= rsiOversold)
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)

// RECALCULATES
if (strategy.opentrades > 0 and not na(strategy.position_avg_price) and na(avgBuyPrice))
    avgBuyPrice := strategy.position_avg_price
    safetyTradeSize := strategy.position_size * 2
    safetyTradePrice := avgBuyPrice * (1 - safetyTrade)
    takeProfitPrice := avgBuyPrice * (1 + takeProfit)

// SAFETY TRADE 
if (strategy.opentrades > 0 and safetyTradeExecuted == false and close <= safetyTradePrice)
    strategy.entry("SFTY", strategy.long, qty=safetyTradeSize)
    safetyTradeExecuted := true
    // RECALCULATES
    avgBuyPrice := strategy.position_avg_price
    takeProfitPrice := avgBuyPrice * (1 + takeProfit)

// TAKE PROFIT
if (strategy.opentrades > 0 and close >= takeProfitPrice)
    strategy.close_all("TP")
    // RESETS
    avgBuyPrice := na
    takeProfitPrice := na
    safetyTradeExecuted := false
    safetyTradeSize := na
    safetyTradePrice := na


By default, you can only have one open position.
In order to place safety orders, you need to change the pyramiding option. You can do that either with the gui (from Properties tab) or with code pyramiding.
strategy("NEW", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=2, pyramiding=3)

